# What is this dots in pandas.DataFrame.boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I use [boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) from pandas dataframe.

When I executed the code, then I saw some small dots as below image.

**Just wonder what is that dots? and what is it for?**

[image]

Comment: I can not see the image because of my network restriction but i think you're talking about `outliers` in data

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Thanks for the term. Do you know what to do with this outliers?

Comment: Few of the techniques are, 1. convert them into 75th or `95th percentile **or** 2. remove them from the data

Answer (score 2):

I thought this picture explains boxplot

[image: Reading a Box-and-Whisker Plot]

Answer (score 0):

From you the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) you shared: `Outlier points are those past the end of the whiskers`.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier): `An outlier is a data point that differs significantly from other observations. An outlier may be due to variability in the measurement or it may indicate experimental error; the latter are sometimes excluded from the data set.`

Comment: It depends from your measurements: can be both variability in the measurements or experimental error. Check Wikipedia for a complete explanation

Comment: From the picture you posted: `identify any values that look wrong`, I think that the `outliers` are those values

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/how-to-remove-outliers-using-box-plot

Comment: @HoangTranSon Of course it doesn't mean they are wrong or error. The outlier itself does not have a clear definition. Some would consider any sample outside +/- 3 standard deviation an outlier. how to treat outliers depends heavily on your sample size and the cost of new samples. If your sample size is small you may evaluate the samples marked as outlier one by one and see if they are truly outliers..